# How to select a binary tree node uniformly at random

Tags: algorithms, trees, correctness-proof, randomness, sampling

The exercise I'm trying to solve is

> You are implementing a binary search tree class from scratch, which, in addition, to insert, find and delete, has a method `getRandomNode()` which returns a random node from the tree. All nodes should be equally likely to be chosen. Design and implement an algorithm for `getRandomNode()`, and explain how you would implement the rest of the methods.

The answer from the book is:

```
 1  class TreeNode {
 2    private int data;
 3    public TreeNode left;
 4    public TreeNode right;
 5    private int size = 0;
 ...
12    public TreeNode getRandomNode() {
13      int leftSize = left == null ? 0 : left.size();
14      Random random = new Random();
15      int index = random.nextInt(size);
16      if (index < leftSize) {
17        return left.getRandomNode();
18      } else if (index == leftSize) {
19        return this;
20      } else {
21        return right.getRandomNode();
22      }
23    }
...
55  }
```

But here is the problem. With this algorithm, I don't see how nodes are equally likely to be chosen. In line 16, it says if `leftsize > index,` where `index` is a number from 0 to `size`, then the algorithm will continue with the left node, otherwise the right node. It only works when the tree has a depth of 2. When the tree is taller, the probability of each node being chosen will not be equal.

Am I wrong? Does this algorithm work?

Comment: "Does this algorithm work?" If you have the code for it, why don't you create a few really large random trees. Then repeatedly call `getRandomNode()` on the trees and see if the distribution of the count returned of each node is uniform. It's not a definitive answer, but should give you some perspective.

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm works just fine.

Note that each node's `size` field tells you the total number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that node. Throughout this answer, I'm just going to assume that a child's `size` is zero if the child is `null`.  Thus, for any node in the tree, we have

```
this.size == left.size + 1 + right.size
```

Consider the root of the tree.  If we choose a node of the tree uniformly at random, then it should be in the left subtree with probability `left.size/size`, it should be the root node with probability `1/size` and it should be in the right subtree with probability `right.size/size`.  By the equation above, these three probabilities add up to 1.  If you look at lines 15–22, the algorithm implements exactly this probability distribution.  It generates a uniform random integer in the range `0 .. size-1`.  If this number is in the range `0 .. left.size-1`, the algorithm picks a random node from the left subtree; if it's equal to `left.size`, it picks the root and, otherwise, it picks a random node from the right subtree.

And the argument I gave doesn't depend on the node you consider being the root, so the recursive calls behave as they should.  The algorithm doesn't care about the depth of the nodes: it just recurses down the subtree and chooses subtrees with the correct probability.

Comment: The last paragraph can be made rigorous by performing an inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show that this algorithm indeed randomly chooses a node according to the uniform distribution.

Consider the root node. We have two subtrees: the left subtree with the size $s_l$ and the right subtree with the size $s_r$. The total number of nodes in the tree is $size = 1 + s_r + s_l$. Now, I want to prove that distribution is uniform, i.e. for any node $e$, $P(e)=\frac{1}{size}$ (probability that the algorithm chooses $e$).

There are three possibilities, either $e$ is the root, or $e$ is in the left subtree, or $e$ is the right subtree.

If $e$ is the root node, then `index = random.nextInt(size)`uniformly selects an integer between $0$ and $size-1$, and the statement `if (index == leftSize)` is true with the probability $\frac{1}{size}$.

If the node $e$ is in the left subtree then the probability that the statement `if (index < leftSize)` is true, $P(InLeft)$, is equal to $\frac{s_l}{size}$ and the conditional probability that the node $e$ is chosen given it is in the left subtree is $P(e \mid InLeft)=\frac{1}{s_l}$. Thus the probability [$e$ is in the left subtree] AND [$e$ is chosen] is equal to 
$$P(InLeft \cap e \text{ is chosen }) = P(InLeft)P(e \mid InLeft) = \frac{s_l}{size}\frac{1}{s_l} = \frac{1}{size}$$

If the node $e$ is in the right subtree then using the same argument as in the previous case we have $P(InRight)P(e\mid InRight) = \frac{s_r}{size}\frac{1}{s_r} = \frac{1}{size}$.

Thus the distribution is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arbitrary node $n_k$ which is reached from the root $n_0$ along path $(n_0, n_1, \dots, n_k)$. We will explicitly compute the probability of $n_k$ being chosen.

Observe that when visiting $n_{i-1}$ with $i>0$, that node itself is selected with probability

$\qquad\displaystyle \frac{1}{\operatorname{size}(n_i)}$, and

child $n_i$ is recursed to with probability

$\qquad\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{size}(n_i)}{\operatorname{size}(n_{i-1})}$.

Hence, because all the choices are stochastically independent, the probability to select $n_k$ is

$\qquad\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{size}(n_1)}{\operatorname{size}(n_0)} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{size}(n_2)}{\operatorname{size}(n_1)} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{\operatorname{size}(n_k)}{\operatorname{size}(n_{k-1})} \cdot \frac{1}{\operatorname{size}(n_k)} 
\quad=\quad \frac{1}{\operatorname{size}(n_0)}$,

what was to show.

Fill in the details for a formal proof.